# Convert json to different format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have JSON in this format.
I can't figure out this problem 
I am using Object.values and object.keys with Array.prototype.map() but anything my algorithm didn't do what i want.

```
[
{
"2018-01-01": [
  {
    "firstname": "mati",
    "lastname": "mati",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": 0,
    "free_minutes": 480,
    "task_date": "2018-01-01"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "andrzej",
    "lastname": "owsianka",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": 0,
    "free_minutes": 480,
    "task_date": "2018-01-01"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "asd",
    "lastname": "asd",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": 0,
    "free_minutes": 480,
    "task_date": "2018-01-01"
  }
],
"2018-01-02": [
  {
    "firstname": "mati",
    "lastname": "mati",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": "70",
    "task_date": "2018-01-02",
    "free_minutes": 410
  },
  {
    "firstname": "andrzej",
    "lastname": "owsianka",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": "360",
    "task_date": "2018-01-02",
    "free_minutes": 120
  },
  {
    "firstname": "asd",
    "lastname": "asd",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": "30",
    "task_date": "2018-01-02",
    "free_minutes": 450
  }
],
"2018-01-03": [
  {
    "firstname": "mati",
    "lastname": "mati",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": "0",
    "task_date": "2018-01-03",
    "free_minutes": 480
  },
  {
    "firstname": "andrzej",
    "lastname": "owsianka",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": 0,
    "free_minutes": 480,
    "task_date": "2018-01-03"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "asd",
    "lastname": "asd",
    "userid": null,
    "total_minutes": 0,
    "free_minutes": 480,
    "task_date": "2018-01-03"
  }
]
}
]
```

I want get JSON in this format or very similar to this format

```
[
{
"firstname": "mati",
"lastname": "mati",
"2018-01-01": "480",
"2018-01-02": 480,
"2018-01-03": 480
},
{
"firstname": "andrzej",
"lastname": "owsianka",
"2018-01-01": "480",
"2018-01-02": 480,
"2018-01-03": 480
},
{
"firstname": "asd",
"lastname": "asd",
"2018-01-01": "480",
"2018-01-02": 480,
"2018-01-03": 480
}
]
```

How I have to map data to get something like that ?
I fight with that about 2 hrs but, I didn't invent anything sense.

Comment: Please share your effort.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: any code samples that you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `reduce` and `forEach`, and map the dates based on `firstname` and `lastname`

```
var output = Object.values( arr.reduce( function(a, c){
   Object.keys( c ).forEach( function( date ){
      var arr2 = c[ date ];
      arr2.forEach( function(item){
        var keyObj = {firstname:item.firstname, lastname:item.lastname};
        var key = JSON.stringify( keyObj );
        a[ key ] = a[ key ] || keyObj;
        a[ key ][date] = item.free_minutes;
      });
   });
   return a;
} ,{}));
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
  "2018-01-01": [{
      "firstname": "mati",
      "lastname": "mati",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": 0,
      "free_minutes": 480,
      "task_date": "2018-01-01"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "andrzej",
      "lastname": "owsianka",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": 0,
      "free_minutes": 480,
      "task_date": "2018-01-01"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "asd",
      "lastname": "asd",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": 0,
      "free_minutes": 480,
      "task_date": "2018-01-01"
    }
  ],
  "2018-01-02": [{
      "firstname": "mati",
      "lastname": "mati",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": "70",
      "task_date": "2018-01-02",
      "free_minutes": 410
    },
    {
      "firstname": "andrzej",
      "lastname": "owsianka",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": "360",
      "task_date": "2018-01-02",
      "free_minutes": 120
    },
    {
      "firstname": "asd",
      "lastname": "asd",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": "30",
      "task_date": "2018-01-02",
      "free_minutes": 450
    }
  ],
  "2018-01-03": [{
      "firstname": "mati",
      "lastname": "mati",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": "0",
      "task_date": "2018-01-03",
      "free_minutes": 480
    },
    {
      "firstname": "andrzej",
      "lastname": "owsianka",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": 0,
      "free_minutes": 480,
      "task_date": "2018-01-03"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "asd",
      "lastname": "asd",
      "userid": null,
      "total_minutes": 0,
      "free_minutes": 480,
      "task_date": "2018-01-03"
    }
  ]
}];

var output = Object.values( arr.reduce( function(a, c){
   Object.keys( c ).forEach( function( date ){
      var arr2 = c[ date ];
      arr2.forEach( function(item){
        var keyObj = {firstname:item.firstname, lastname:item.lastname};
        var key = JSON.stringify( keyObj );
        a[ key ] = a[ key ] || keyObj;
        a[ key ][date] = item.free_minutes;
      });
   });
   return a;
} ,{}));

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate and accumulate all nested parts in a single plain result accumulator, this is the pseudocode:

```
var result=[];

for each dates in json
        for each date in dates
            for each entry in date
                result[]=entry;
```